# How to get a specific ID in postman

Tags: javascript

I want to get a specific ID of a booking which appears in an array, when I send a get request to : http://94.209.90.18:3001/booking. I get an array of bookingIDs and would like to get the id of the first booking and which I clearly see here that it is 3. But I am constantly getting an assertion error although I used the to.be.deep.equal method:

that is the array, that I get with the booking request:

```
[{
  "bookingid": 3
}, {
  "bookingid": 2
}, {
  "bookingid": 1
}, {
  "bookingid": 9
}, {
  "bookingid": 10
}, {
  "bookingid": 7
}]
```

Test:

```
pm.test("Getting the booking id", function() {
  var bookingid = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(bookingid).not.to.be.undefined;
  console.log(bookingid[1]);
  pm.expect(bookingid[1]).to.deep.eql(3)
});
```

another question how can I verify what I am getting after console.log since I don't see any console in postman.

Thx

Comment: Your position would be `bookingid[0]`, not `bookingid[1]`. You can open the console in the bottom left of the screen

Comment: `bookingid[0]` is an object in your test: it's `{"bookingid": 3}`. You need `bookingid[0].bookingid` - that is **3**. Try to use different names for different things. You could (for example) name your response array: `bookingIdResponseArray`, then it's harder to mismatch your variables.